# Styles/Positioning

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm working on this site for a friend, & whilst adding a Facebook Like button to the Left Box 3, I have messed up the styling somehow.
Everything is squashed into one column.

Can someone please help me? What is causing this?

www.stonehouserestaurant.com.au

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add an extra `</div>` right before `<div class="right">` to close the left column.

Comment: Awesome, that was exactly it. Serves me for using a basic text editor. Thanks!